# How to set SQLITE_CONFIG_SERIALIZED in ormlite

Tags: sqlite, ormlite

I am using Ormlite with SQLite in my android app. The app has multiple threads accessing the databse. How to enable SQLITE_CONFIG_SERIALIZED in ormlite?

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use the raw methods in the Daos to send commands to the underlying Sqlite database:

```
http://ormlite.com/docs/raw-update
```

Maybe something like:

```
fooDao.executeRaw("SQLITE_CONFIG_SERIALIZED;");
```

But it seems for this to work the Android Sqlite needs to be built a certain way:

```
http://sqlite.org/c3ref/c_config_getmalloc.html
```